# Nagios: Can I output HTML in my custom plugins?

Tags: nagios

Is it possible to output HTML in my nagios plugins?

I'd just like a `<br/>` (new line) to show up in status of my plugin (I'd like error messages to include a reasonable amount of useful information in the case of a multiple transaction jmeter script).

I tried outputting `<br/>` in my plugin, but nagios converts it to text rather than displaying it as HTML.

Comment: You should check Nagios documentation, 'CGI Configuration File Options', namely 'escape_html_tags' variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As default no. But you could modify the code of the display page to parse the output for line breaks?